# What is Beyond Paraparam in Saiva Siddhanta?

Tags: shiva, shaiva-siddhanta, nayanar

> 2945: Transcendental Union Beyond Word and Speech
>   As salt in water, in Lord I mixed,
>   Transcending Param and Paraparam states,
>   Beyond word and speech I in union merged;
>   "How was It?"-you ask
>   "It was It"-I say.

It's from Tirumantiram

Please someone explain me. Does that mean there's something beyond Paraparam?